# AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I've got this error. Why?

```
File "/k.py", line 257, in deskJ
    eremuak = aFileLine.strip().split('\t')
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Code

```
def deskribapenaJaso(self, aFileLine):
    eremuak = aFileLine.strip().split('\t')
    print(eremuak) #printNothing
```

aFileLine = It's the X line of a file

Comment: aFileLine is the file object **not** a line from the file. `aFileLine.readline().strip().split('\t')` will get a line but there are most likely better ways to do what you want.

Comment: Yes you need to do a aFileLine.readline() to actually get the string

Answer (score 4):

You are using `str` methods on an open file object.

You can read the file as a list of lines by simply calling `list()` on the file object:

```
with open('goodlines.txt') as f:
    mylist = list(f)
```